# Storing XValidation (Cross Validation) Folds in Rapidminer?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, rapidminer, cross-validation, text-classification

I have tried a lot via code to save the test/train split samples for each fold in 10-fold cross validation(stratified) but couldn't manage to do that...

Is there any way to save the test/train splits samples (not model) in rapid miner ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was about to suggest this for your previous post.

The `Store` operator that lets you store an example set in the repository. To allow the names of the different folds to be distinguished, you would need to have a macro that changes each time the operator executes. You then use the macro name when configuring the name in the `Store` operator. To create a macro use the `Generate Macro` operator which you can also use to increment it within the cross validation operator.

Comment: Great it worked out for me partially because 'Model' build by classifier inside XValidation operator is stored as SimpleDistributionModel but i need an example set for it. Secondly as per knowledge k-fold cross validation (stratified) build model on k-1 folds and test it on kth fold but the example set "Naive Bayes(i am using it inside XValidation operator)"  yields opposite i.e. as classifier output two things exampleset and model so in my case exampleset has samples equivalent to k-1 folds ? Thanks for showing me the way out of problem ..

Comment: Would you mind up-voting the answer to encourage contributors?

Comment: Well, I hope the moderators will say something.